# DropDownList issue with Enums

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums

I'm currently localizing an open source project and I have an issue with Enums.

Here is my Enums.cs (not the whole file, just part of where the issue appears).

```
 public enum ModeratorLevel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Sahip")]
        Owner = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Moderatör")]
        Moderator = 2,
        [Display(Name = "Temizlikçi")]
        Janitor = 3,
        [Display(Name = "Boyacı")]
        Designer = 4,
        [Display(Name = "Paylaşımcı")]
        Submitter = 99
    }
```

and this is my View (again, not the whole file, contains only the codes that I want to fix)

```
@{
    string subverseName = ViewBag.SubverseName;

    var levelsAvailable  = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ModeratorLevel)).OfType<ModeratorLevel>();
    var currentLevel = ModeratorPermission.Level(User.Identity.Name, subverseName);
    levelsAvailable = levelsAvailable.Where(x => x > currentLevel || currentLevel == ModeratorLevel.Owner);

}

@* these areas contain other codes is not related to my issue *@

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("foo", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Power, levelsAvailable.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() }), new { @class = "form-control"} )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Power, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>

@* these areas contain other codes is not related to my issue *@
```

and this is output;
[dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIPbO.png)

aaand now, What I want? 
I want to display DisplayNames instead Enum values.
The outpot looks like:

- foo = Owner
- Moderator
- Janitor
- Designer
- Submitter

But I want to show it looks like:

- foo = Sahip
- Moderatör
- Temizlikçi
- Boyacı
- Paylaşımcı

But in this change, changes must be only visual. We shouldn't change any code that affects to Enum's function. I just want to show only DisplayNames instead of Enum values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add an extension method :

```
public static string DisplayName(this Enum value)
    {
        Type enumType = value.GetType();
        var enumValue = Enum.GetName(enumType, value);
        MemberInfo member = enumType.GetMember(enumValue)[0];

        var attrs = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);
        var outString = ((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).Name;

        if (((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).ResourceType != null)
        {
            outString = ((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).GetName();
        }

        return outString;
    }
```

and then use it in the view :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Power, levelsAvailable.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.DisplayName(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() }), new { @class = "form-control"} )
```

Comment: Sorry for my newbie question but where should I add this first string code?

Comment: you can  create a class in your project add the method to it

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough experience on asp and MVC (Im just trying to learn and localizing this project.  Could you share a document with me how to do it? Or can you explain it more spesific :( Thank you.

Comment: you can create a folder in your web project "Helpers" for example. then add new class in the folder "EnumHelper" put the DisplayName method in this class. go to the view and the reference to the helper @using nameSpace.EnumHelper

Comment: and after all, that worked like a charm. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `EnumDropDownListFor` helper

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Power)
```

Comment: This will not work because the OP does not want a dropdown for all the items in the enum. The OP is filtering them if you pay attention.

Comment: In addition, the `EnumDropDownListFor()` is only available in MVC-5.1 or higher